# my phone won't store to my memory card

Tags: sony-xperia

I have a Sony Xperia M (C1905) and have a SanDisk ultra 16gb memory card but it won't save any of my apps pictures or videos or anything to it is there anyway to fix this?? It keeps telling me I have insufficient space because it's used my internal storage but still have 16gb on my memory card why???

Comment: From your comment on the answer I assume you can write to it (and already transfered files) – so what you're really asking about is how to have your apps moved over, is that correct? If not: what error are you receiving?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one - Open Settings > Storage > Transfer data > Check all. This moves all the content especially Photos, Music, Videos from internal memory to SD Memory card. 
Some video and audio formats may not support this operation. For moving those use ES File Explorer from Play store.

Comment: I've done that but I really want to move apps not just files

Comment: Xperia doesn't support this operation even if you root the device. That's a weird limitation by Sony. Developers are still trying on this thing.

Comment: Developers in the sense people on XDA Developers website.